# What are requirements for Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-studio

I have an Acer Aspire 3682 WXMi laptop, 40gb HD, 512mb ram.  Will this take Ubuntu, or more specifically Ubuntu Studio?

Comment: Definitevly not Ubuntu, better aim for Xubuntu or Lubuntu. This might be useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Answer (score 0):

The [formal requirements](http://ubuntustudio.org/download/) seem to meet what you have. However, you would not regret adding more memory to that machine, as "It is highly recommended that you have 2GB or more memory though so that the system will perform much better." Your system *will* accept more memory, I checked.

If you are not able to add memory, then consider using 32-bit (i386) [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) and picking apps from the Studio suite one at a time.

There's also an [Ubuntu Forums section specifically for Studio](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=335).